# Différence entre l'orthographe de «votre» et «vôtre» et entre «notre» et «nôtre»

Tags: grammaire, orthographe

D'où vient la différence entre l'orthographe de « votre » et de « vôtre » et celle entre «notre» et «nôtre» ?

Quand doit-on utiliser l'un ou l'autre ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Notre* et *votre* sont des déterminants possessifs (donc toujours faisant toujours partie d'un groupe nominal: notre explication, votre question) tandis que *nôtre* et *vôtre* sont des pronoms (toujours accompagnés d'un article défini: "Cette question, c'était la vôtre ?" "Non, la nôtre, on y a déjà répondu")

Ces mots étaient à l'origine *nostre* et *vostre*, respectivement, sans distinction entre adjectif, déterminant et pronom. Aucune distinction nette n'existait entre la classe des pronoms et celle des déterminants en ancien français (par example, on utilisait ceste aussi bien comme déterminant -fr.mod: cette- que comme pronom -fr.mod: celle-ci-) et ce n'est que durant la transition entre l'ancien et le moyen français que l'usage commence à sélectionner certaine variantes ou formes déclinées comme pronoms et d'autres comme déterminants.

Par example, le latin meum avait donné en français un descendant avec l'accent tonique sur la première syllabe (mien: /'me.um/ > /'mɛ.ʊm/ > */'mɛ:.on/ > */'mɛ:n/ > /'mɪ̯ɛn/ > /'mɪ̯̃ẽn/ > /mjɛ̃/) et un descendant atone (mon: /me.um/ > /mɛ.ʊm/ */mɛ.on/ > */mə.on/ > /mon/ > /mõn/ > /mɔ̃/). La forme atone devient spécialisée comme déterminant tandis que la forme tonique sert de pronom et d'adjectif (et éventuellement de pronom uniquement).

*Nostre* et *vostre* ne possédaient cependant pas de formes distinctes qui auraient pu être spécialisées comme déterminant et pronom. Par contre, un changement phonétique était en cours qui n'allait avoir un résultat différent selon que les syllabes étaient toniques ou atone: les /s/ en fin de syllabe, déjà débucalisés (transformés en /h/), étaient en train de disparaître carrément. En position tonique, cette disparation est compensée par l'allongement de la voyelle précédente: nostre /'nɔs.trə/ devient /'nɔ:.trə/, ce qui devient en français moderne /no(ː)tʁ/. En position atone, la consonne disparaît en général purement et simplement, sans compensation: nostre /nɔs.trə/ devient /nɔ.trə/, ce qui devient en français moderne /nɔtʁ/.

Ce changement a donc procuré opportunément aux locuteurs deux formes distinctes qui pouvaient être utilisée l'une comme déterminant, l'autre comme pronom ou adjectif. Les déterminant étant toujours atone, c'est la version avec voyelle courte et ouverte, (/nɔ.trə/ > /nɔtʁ/) qui s'impose dans ce rôle, tandis que la version avec voyelle longue et fermée (/'nɔ:.trə/ > /no(ː)tʁ/) devient le pronom.

Initialement cette différence de prononciation n'est pas marquée par l'orthographe (on continue à écrire vostre/nostre ou leur version abrégée vôtre/nôtre dans les deux rôles), mais lors de la standardisation de la langue, les grammairiens assignent l'orthographe sans accent au déterminant et celle avec au pronom.

Attention quand même: tous les dialectes n'ont pas développé ou conservé cette distinction dans prononciation et prononcer vôtre et nôtre avec un o ouvert est courant.

Une autre différence entre ces deux paires de mots est que les déterminants notre et votre ont gardé leur pluriel originel (nos et vos) tandis que celui des pronoms le/la nôtre et le/la vôtre ont été régularisés sur le modèle des noms communs: les nôtre**s** et les vôtre**s**.